# Update Local SQL Server with a Bash Script

Tags: sql-server, bash, amazon-s3

**Question:**
What is the correct format to use in my bash script to be able to run the -Q option?

**Case:** Update local database from S3 every night to run reports on our on-premise server

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#get latest file from S3
BACKUP_MARKETING=`aws s3 ls [some_folder]/[some_subfolder]/ --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`

#download the file locally
aws s3 cp s3://[some_folder]/$BACKUP_MARKETING /var/opt/mssql/backup/marketing

#get the file name
BAK_MARKETING=`find [folder]/ -type f -name "*.bak"`

#drop the database to avoid conflicts from not backing it up
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U [username] -P '[password]' -Q 'DROP DATABASE [db_name]'

#restore the database
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U [username] -P '[password]' -Q RESTORE DATABASE "[db_name]" FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/$BAK_MARKETING" WITH MOVE "[db_name]" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/[db_name].MDF", MOVE "[db_name]_log" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/[db_name].LDF"
```

**Error**

```
Sqlcmd: 'DATABASE" "[db_name]" "FROM" "DISK" "=" "/var/opt/mssql/backup/marketing/[db_name].bak" "WITH" "MOVE" "[db_name]" "TO" "/var/opt/mssql/data/[db_name].MDF," "MOVE" "[db_name]_log" "TO" "/var/opt/mssql/data/[db_name].LDF': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

Comment: I'd use an array for the the instance that you're trying to build a command/options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had to concatenate my variables on the SQL command. Here is the working version plus I added the REPLACE option to it

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U [username] -P '[password]' -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE [db_name] FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/'**$BAK_FILE**'" WITH REPLACE, MOVE "[db_name]" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/[db_name].MDF", MOVE "[db_name]_Log" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/[db_name].LDF"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the -i Option instead? 
I had some problems as well using Q, so i replaced it with -i and placed the code within a .sql file instead. 
I ended up with;

```
SET SQLusername=sa
SET SQLpassword=password
SET SQLserver=dnsnameorIp
SET SQLdatabase=databasename
sqlcmd -U %SQLusername% -P %SQLpassword% -S %SQLserver% -d %SQLdatabase% -i mycode.sql -o outputResult.txt
```

Comment: This were on a windows server so i'm not sure if there is any differences.

Comment: I won't be able to get the *.bak file name if I add my code in a .sql file though